# Yii2 - How To Add a CSS class to an ActiveForm Field

Tags: yii2

This is the activeform field. I would like to know how to add a css class to it.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'url')->label(false); ?>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add it with

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255, 'class' => 'your class'])->label(false); ?>
```

As a rule you can pass html elements when telling activeField what type it should be. The default is textInput so that is why your code works, but if you want to change the input then you have to explicitly tell it the type of input.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html

Comment: Remember that if you are using a bootstrap theme, you will probably need  to add "form-control" to the css class list: `'class'=>'your class form-control'`

Comment: can i add "id" fill input in textInput ? i want modify this fill input in jquery

Comment: You should be able to yes

Answer (score 3):

```
<?= $form->field($addWithdrawRequest, 'amount', ['options' => ['tag' => false]])->textInput(['class' => 'form-control col-lg-6 amount','required'=>true,'style' => 'background-color: #fff !important;','placeholder'=>"Enter Amount To Withdraw"])->label(false)?>
```