# How to add a css class to a ActiveForm field in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

There are other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995827/yii2-how-to-add-a-css-class-to-an-actionform-field), which suggest that I can add a class as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name_pu')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'punjabi']) ?>
```

**THAT WORKS BUT **

but this replaces the `form-control` class given by bootstrap, which I don't want.

How can I ADD my own class,  so as to get this result

```
<input type="text" id="regs-name_pu" class="form-control punjabi" name="Regs[name_pu]" maxlength="100">
```

Comment: I am looking for something dynamic,not hardcoding classes that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add the needed class :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name_pu')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control punjabi']) ?>
```

Comment: can we have a better solution?

Comment: because if I change my form layout and design, outside of it, I'll have to come back to this and replace the class again!

Comment: someone downvoted my question. if you think this helps future readers, kindly upvote. I don't find anything like 'no research' in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name_pu')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control punjabi']) ?>
```

Comment: can we have a better solution

Comment: You can set `$my_form_class = 'form-control punjabi'`, then `<?= $form->field($model, 'name_pu')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => $my_form_class]) ?>`